# Getting user checkin information based on place_id from Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-checkins

I was wondering if there is any way to get user checkin information for different places based on the place_id. Facebook documentation keeps changing around and I'm not sure if this is possible now? Seems like it was possible in older API versions.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkins are deprecated since Graph API v2.0. You can get the total count (field `were_here_count`) of checkins to a place with a call like

```
GET /BrandenburgerTorBerlin?fields=id,name,were_here_count
```

which gives the result

```
{
  "id": "145183205532558", 
  "name": "Brandenburger Tor", 
  "were_here_count": 128511
}
```

Comment: Ah that sucks. Thank you for your help.